# 'str' object has no attribute 'close with popen.python

Tags: python

I am using the command `os.popen` in python and when I try to close it I get the error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'close
```

how can I fix this?
I tried reading it repeatedly in another line but this still didn't work.
this is the code lines:

```
 p = os.popen(command, "r").read()
 f_temp_command = open("%s/%s%s" % (LOG_DIR, file, LOG_EXT), "w")
 f_temp_command.writelines([l for l in p.splitlines()])
 p.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
p = os.popen(command, "r").read()
```

binds `p` to the result of `.read()`, not to the result of `os.popen()`. You want:

```
p = os.popen(command, "r") 
r = p.read()
do_something_with(r)
p.close()
```

or better:

```
with os.popen(command, "r") as p:
    r = p.read()
# no need to close p anymore, it's already done
```

As a side note, you don't need the list expression here:
    f_temp_command.writelines([l for l in r.splitlines()])

since `r.splitlines()` already returns a list, so you could replace it with:

```
f_temp_command.writelines(r.splitlines())
```

or even with:

```
f_temp_command.write(r)
```

Comment: subprocess.popen is preferred over os.popen

Comment: thanks. it did solve this but now i get the error:      f_temp_command.writelines([l for l in p.splitlines()])
  File "C:\Users\efrat.shpilman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\os.py", line 1009, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._stream, name)
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'splitlines'. probably because i didnt close the file yet. is there a way through it?

Comment: @Adamso you can't indeed call `splitlines()` on a file object - you want to use the variable bound to the result of `p.read()`  (`r` in my example) instead, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can not close it bacause `read` method return `str` object. Use an intermediate variable to store the result.

```
p = os.popen(command, "r")
res = p.read()
f_temp_command = open("%s/%s%s" % (LOG_DIR, file, LOG_EXT), "w")
f_temp_command.writelines([l for l in res.splitlines()])
p.close()
```